# What are the proper output settings for 1080p HD animation for Yotube?

Tags: rendering, file-format

I did a "film grain" test by animating the seed value in Cycles, and rendered at 1080p (1920x1080). I originally rendered the png sequence into an AVI JPG format (300mb) and uploaded it to Youtube, but Youtube compressed it to the point where most of the actual noise is no longer visible.

I tried a couple other formats because Youtube specified H.264 as it's ideal format. MPEG-4 compression didn't have good results and I got an error if I tried to increase the bit-rate past 2000. I finally tried the H.264 encoding preset and checked Lossless Output, 50,000 Bit Rate, GOP Size = 1 (I'm not sure what this does), and the results are pretty close to the same noise level as the original AVI JPG. However I uploaded this to Youtube and got the same poor results as before.

What output settings should I be using?

For comparison, here's the Youtube link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xmei5DSmkbQ
And the H.264 with H.264 encoding good version on my Google Drive: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7W-I44-6uuSOHlUSFRqYTVjWWM/edit?usp=sharing (80mb) You need to download it to view it properly.
[image]

I'm not sure if I like the results of the test, but I still need to figure out the proper encoding for HD videos for Youtube in general either way.

Comment: This may be a case YouTube trying to help you when you really don't want their help. I know that they have recommended upload formats, but it's likely that they still transcode regardless of the format/codec you choose to send them.

Comment: YouTube uses really agressive compression, there's nothing you can really do about it other than to reduce the amount of grain.

Comment: Well these comments are disappointing. Thanks for the input though. I did an HD test with a noiseless render from Blender Internal and it was fine, so yes, it seems like this is just that Youtube's compression method is particularly unfriendly to grainy footage. If anyone has specific experience or ideas for a work-around/ how to solve this I'll leave this open. I might also try a test with lower noise, but I would expect even low-noise to cause compression issues because it's the fact that it's moving frame to frame not the detail itself that seems to be the issue.

Comment: Have you tried uploading to Vimeo? As far as I know they compress the video much less.

Comment: @David: I did try Vimeo. It gave no better results.

Comment: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en